# Map rows of one dataframe with the column of another dataframe to retrieve the first row of each column from the later table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the below dataframe:

data = pd.DataFrame({ 'col_A' : [1,2,3,4],
                       'col_B' : ["x","xx","xxx","y"]});data

```
   col_A col_B
0      1     x
1      2    xx
2      3   xxx
3      4     y
```

I am trying to create a new dataframe that has an overview of all columns with the

- Data Type of each data.column
- the first row of each column
- and some metrics for each column

While I manage to create an new dataframe with the datatype of each column

```
DataTypes = pd.DataFrame(data.dtypes, columns= ["Type"]).reset_index().rename(columns={"index": "Column"}); DataTypes
```

Output:

```
  Column    Type
0  col_A   int64
1  col_B  object
```

I struggle with bring the first value from data table and a metric:

Desired Output:

```
  Column    Type  Value  Max
0  col_A   int64    1     4
1  col_B  object    x    n.a
```

Any Idea on how I can map the rows of the DataType table with the Data columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with `Series` created by [`dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html) and [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with `metrics` `DataFrame` created by [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html):

```
a = data.dtypes.rename('Type')
b = data.iloc[0].rename('first')
c = data.agg(['min','max', 'mean']).T

df = pd.concat([a,b,c], axis=1)
print (df)
         Type first max mean min
col_A   int64     1   4  2.5   1
col_B  object     x   y  NaN   x
```

Comment: `data.agg(['min','max', 'mean'])`
`Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-134-e4f10b28a814>", line 1, in <module>
    data.agg(['min','max', 'mean'])

  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3.4\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2672, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'agg'`

Comment: It is new function in pandas 0.20.0, what is your pandas version?